# Counting of repeating words in the paragraph in c#

Tags: c#, text

i want to count the number of words in paragraph and also want to count the number of appearance of words in paragraph. Mean how much time a word is appear in the paragraph.

I am to confuse in this problem. In first step I have *split* the paragraph into array using `Split` method in C# and also count the number of words in paragraph. But I am failed in counting the number of appearance of the words in the paragraph.

I need your help friends. Please give me any solution in C#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: As a hint... One approach would be to create a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the word is the key and the count is the value.  Loop over your list of words and, for each word, either add it as new to the dictionary or increment its existing count in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for like a sample code?

```
class CountWords  
{  
    static void Main()  
    {  
        string text = @"Historically, the world of data and the world of objects" +  
          @" have not been well integrated. Programmers work in C# or Visual Basic" +  
          @" and also in SQL or XQuery. On the one side are concepts such as classes," +  
          @" objects, fields, inheritance, and .NET APIs. On the other side" +  
          @" are tables, columns, rows, nodes, and separate languages for dealing with" +  
          @" them. Data types often require translation between the two worlds; there are" +  
          @" different standard functions. Because the object world has no notion of query, a" +  
          @" query can only be represented as a string without compile-time type checking or" +  
          @" IntelliSense support in the IDE. Transferring data from SQL tables or XML trees to" +  
          @" objects in memory is often tedious and error-prone.";  

        string searchTerm = "data";  

        //Convert the string into an array of words  
        string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':',     ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  

        // Create the query.  Use the InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparision to     match "data" and "Data"
        var matchQuery = from word in source  
                         where word.Equals(searchTerm,     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)  
                         select word;  

        // Count the matches, which executes the query.  
        int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();  
        Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences(s) of the search term \"{1}\" were found.", wordCount, searchTerm);  

        // Keep console window open in debug mode  
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");  
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }  
}  
/* Output:  
   3 occurrences(s) of the search term "data" were found.  
*/
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a way to search for a specific work, just a way to show a list of unique words with the count for each.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can first split the paragraph into an array of words using the Split method and then counts the total number of words using the Length property of the resulting array then create a Dictionary object to keep track of the number of appearances of each word. Below code loops, through each word in the array and checks if it already exists in the wordCounts dictionary. If it does, it increments the count; otherwise, it adds the word to the dictionary with a count of 1.

```
string paragraph = @"Historically, the world of data and the world of objects" +  
          @" have not been well integrated. Programmers work in C# or Visual Basic" +  
          @" and also in SQL or XQuery. On the one side are concepts such as classes," +  
          @" objects, fields, inheritance, and .NET APIs. On the other side" +  
          @" are tables, columns, rows, nodes, and separate languages for dealing with" +  
          @" them. Data types often require translation between the two worlds; there are" +  
          @" different standard functions. Because the object world has no notion of query, a" +  
          @" query can only be represented as a string without compile-time type checking or" +  
          @" IntelliSense support in the IDE. Transferring data from SQL tables or XML trees to" +  
          @" objects in memory is often tedious and error-prone."; 

// Split the paragraph into an array of words
string[] words = paragraph.Split(new char[] {' ', ',', '.', ';', ':', '!', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Count the total number of words
int wordCount = words.Length;
Console.WriteLine("Total number of words: " + wordCount);

// Count the number of appearances of each word
Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (wordCounts.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        wordCounts[word]++;
    }
    else
    {
        wordCounts[word] = 1;
    }
}

// Print the results
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in wordCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word: " + entry.Key + ", Count: " + entry.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's come to terms and define "word", if we agree that word is

> Non-empty sequence of Unicode letters, minuses and apostrophes which consists of at least one letter

E.g. words are `"Abc"`, `"isn't"`, `"Ἀθῆναι"`, `"error-prone"`; not words `"''"`, `"123"`

then we can come to *regular expression* pattern

```
[\p{L}'\-]*\p{L}+[\p{L}'\-]*
```

here

```
 [\p{L}'\-]* - zero or more Unicode letters, minuses or apostrophes
 \p{L}+      - at least one Unicode letter
 [\p{L}'\-]* - zero or more Unicode letters, minuses or apostrophes
```

and we can obtain all such words as

```
var words = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"[\p{L}'\-]*\p{L}+[\p{L}'\-]*")   
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value);
```

Now we should decide which words are equal; if we want to compare words character by character while *ignoring case* (`"A" == "a" != "AB" != "a'" != "'A"`) we can put it as

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "A big (case) of a simple case.";

...

// Key   - word
// Value - word repetition count
var words = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"[\p{L}']*\p{L}+[\p{L}']*")
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .GroupBy(word => word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

Let's have a look:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key.ToLower(),20} : {pair.Value,3}"));
```

Output:

```
                   a :   2
                 big :   1
                case :   2
                  of :   1
              simple :   1
```